# Syntax highlighting for proof assistants

Tags: discussion, formatting, syntax-highlighting

In [my answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/8/8) to the question about the "Hello World" of proof assistants, the code is very monochromatic:

```
plus_comm =
fun n m : nat =>
nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + m = m + n0)
  (plus_n_0 m)
  (fun (y : nat) (H : y + m = m + y) =>
   eq_ind (S (m + y))
     (fun n0 : nat => S (y + m) = n0)
     (f_equal S H)
     (m + S y)
     (plus_n_Sm m y)) n
     : forall n m : nat, n + m = m + n
```

The presentation of this code on the Coq Wikipedia page isn't much better, but at least they have used green text for the word `fun`:

[image]

I appreciate that this is probably a longer-term feature request which won't be easy to entertain quickly, but I do think it would be nice if eventually we can get syntax highlighting working for at least the most popular theorem provers such as Coq and Lean.

Comment: It would be great if a staff member could weigh in on what the policy is for syntax highlighting on Area51 sites.

Comment: Perhaps this should be retagged as [feature request], @Nike Dattani?

Comment: @Eric see the edit history.

Comment: Contrary to your comment the accepted answer, this _does_ require "development work" or at least deliberate action by a member of the stack exchange staff, so I think feature-request is probably the right tag.

Comment: But SE is not responsibe for maintaining highlight.js.

Comment: SE has to opt-in for every non-default HLJS language, and it's not clear from the meta.SE post whether they are willing to do that per-site or only network-wide.

Comment: I made a new question with the appropriate tags at [Enabling syntax highlighting of Lean and Coq](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/177/347), along with some history demonstrating we wouldn't be the first SE to request a custom language be enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax highlighting of StackExchange markdown is [based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) on [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/). Quoting from the Meta post:

> Keep in mind that Stack Exchange does not maintain this syntax highlighter (aside from installing newer versions of it), and posting bug reports or feature requests concerning it here on Meta will not get them fixed or implemented.

In case you don't know, beginning a code block with three backticks *and the name of your language* should invoke the highlighting, if it is supported. Example:

```
def hello():
  return "Hello", 1 + 1
```

(It does not work here, if I understand it correctly. But it will on sites such as StackOverflow.)

Comment: Thanks! This basically informs me that there's no "development" work for Stack Exchange to do here other than to keep their syntax highlighter well-maintained and to make sure it's activated here. I've removed the "support" and "feature-request" tags for now.

Answer (score 7):

As Trebor notes, StackExchange uses the external highlight.js library to do syntax highlighting. The current version of highlight.js supports [Lean and Coq](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-languages.html) at least (though Lean is through an external package, so it may not be included). I don't know when these were added or if StackExchange is using that version, but it at least suggests this will be available soon, if not already. I added the coq flag to your code block to test if this will trigger yet; if not, it at least gets that code block ready for when this highlighting is available.

Once this is working and once the site has mods, tags can also have specific syntax highlighting tied to them which sets the default syntax highlighting for the question (and answers?). So they could set the default highlighting on a [coq](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coq) question to be Coq.

Comment: Unfortunately `highlight.js` does not support Lean out of the box; a third-party package, https://github.com/leanprover-community/highlightjs-lean, is needed to support Lean. `highlight.js` has declared they are [no longer willing to support new languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/1689#issuecomment-568644727).