# Enabling syntax highlighting of Lean and Coq

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, formatting, syntax-highlighting

This follows on from [Syntax highlighting for proof assistants](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/347), which establishes that it would be nice to have syntax highlighting, but incorrectly concludes that the ball is not in StackExchange's court.

As mentioned in an answer there, the tool StackExchange uses for highlighting, highlight.js, [supports](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-languages.html) Coq (natively) and Lean (via a third-party extension, [highlightjs-lean](https://github.com/leanprover-community/highlightjs-lean)). Note that [`highlight.js` is no longer accepting new languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/pull/1689#issuecomment-568644727), so the Lean extension will always be third-party.

The list in [the *"What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"* meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) mentions that among the enabled languages is:

> - **Mathematica / Wolfram Language: `lang-mathematica`**, `lang-mma`, (`lang-wl`)
>   (Mathematica SE only)

A little more digging reveals that this feature [was enabled on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50) on 2012-01-18, which was during the Mathematica.SE Private Beta ([which ended](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304?phase=beta) on 2012-01-25). Inspecting the source reveals this has been done by including an additional `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/highlight.js/additional-langs/lang-mma.min.js` file that is not present on most SE sites.

Since there is precedent for enabling niche highlighters on other StackExchange sites during their beta phases, can `lang-coq` ([coq](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coq)) and `lang-lean` ([lean](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lean)) highlighters be enabled on Proof Assistants? <s>Or is this something that should wait for Beta to end?</s>

---

Edit: I'm aware that the [request to add Julia syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355928/147400) is [status-deferred](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred), but thought the situation might be different here since this is not a request for a new site-wide highlighter but just for one SE site, and ProofAssistants certainly does not have the traffic considerations that StackOverflow does!

Comment: Thanks for explaining in more detail, what you were possibly trying to convey to me in the comments on ky question! It's much more clear to me now :)

Comment: @Rob: That's not true any more, if you look at the network traffic for `mathematica.stackexchange.com` you can see it loads `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/highlight.js/additional-langs/lang-mma.min.js?v=5` which is clearly highlight.js and not Prettify.

Comment: It's [status-deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443/282094) and Coq is [not working on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357267/add-lang-ml-language-hint-to-coq-coq-tactic-ltac-tags).

Comment: @Rob: It's not clear to me that either link is relevant. Regarding your first link; that's referring to Julia and StackOverflow, and the considerations for including a new language on SO are clearly quite different than including it on a more niche and low-traffic site like this one. Regarding the second; Mathematica does not work on SO, but does work on Mathematica.SE, so whether things are enabled on SO appears not to be relevant.

This question is a request to enable Coq / Lean *on Proof Assistants*, not network-wide.

Comment: There are [languages that are supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/282094) (you can [see it at work on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ocaml/info)), and a [decision that nothing is being changed/added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374715/support-prolog-in-syntax-highlighting#comment1248364_374715) - that doesn't imply that we don't support your request, just that such requests are being refused by staff. --- Also, for us (at PA.SE), it's not just a couple of languages but a number of more site-specific ones (Mizar / ACL2) that all should be included.

Comment: _"There are languages that are supported"_ - yes, I link to that in my question! I think it would be best to wait for a staff opinion on this specific post rather than extrapolate from network-wide requests elsewhere.

Comment: _"but a number of more site-specific ones (Mizar / ACL2) that all should be included."_ - Mizar seems to indeed be supported by highlight.js, but we have no [tag:mizar] questions right now. If you want to request `ACL2`, you'll need to write a highlighter for it. I requested [tag:coq] and [tag:lean] because those both _do_ have lots of questions, and are supported by highlight.js.

Comment: ACL2 might get by using "Lisp" while we wait; someone more knowledgeable about it than I could probably explain how much of a shortfall there would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm aware that the [request to add Julia syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355928/147400) is [status-deferred](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred), but thought the situation might be different here since this is not a request for a new site-wide highlighter but just for one SE site, and ProofAssistants certainly does not have the traffic considerations that StackOverflow does!

Unfortunately, the fact that this is a request that would affect a single site is something that reduces the request's impact and priority. As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/208518):

> Note that features that need dev time and that are only applicable to your site are unlikely to be given a high priority (...).

For that reason, I'm declining this request.

Comment: That's a shame, but thanks for the official reply. As a compromise, would it be possible to enable the default syntax highlighting without any customization? I believe then moderators would have the power to associate [tag:lean3] with the `lang-haskell` highlighter, which is usually a good approximation.

Comment: Can do, @Eric — you should be able to make that change yourself now.

Comment: Thanks @JNat, I've gone ahead and made that change. Hopefully if the Julia situation is eventually revisited, we can maybe revisit this decision. I guess Mathematica had the benefit of being grandfathered in!

Comment: Downvoting (as it's usual in meta) in order to show disagreement.

Answer (score 2):

Update: as can be seen in the accepted answer, this request was rejected.

As a compromise, syntax highlighting is now enabled for the [stardard list of languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Furthermore, [lean3](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lean3) has been associated with the `haskell` syntax highlighter, as this acts as a reasonable approximation.

On questions not tagged with `lean3`, you can still enable lean-approximation syntax highlighting with

````
```lean3
def my_lean3_code : sorry := sorry
```
````

If users of Coq, Agda, or other unsupported languages have recommendations for approximations of useful highlighting via supported languages, then please ask a new question on this meta site; this is something that the moderators for ProofAssistants.SE can handle without needing to escalate to staff.

Comment: I added `ml` highlighting for [tag:coq] and `haskell` highlighting for [tag:agda].