# Syntax highlighting for Isabelle

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I am to start a project with a student to implement syntax highlighting for Isabelle that could be used here on the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange site.

Is there already some effort aiming this?

Stack Exchange uses [Highlight JS](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js), so we should extend it. However, they [write](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-contribution.html) that:

> Sadly, due to lack of maintainer time we no longer merge new languages grammars into the core library. Instead, the project works by encouraging 3rd party language grammar development by willing contributors ready to help and maintain them. We’re also happy to host those 3rd party language grammars at the highlightjs GitHub organization. Or you’re welcome to host yourself - we’re always happy to link to to new language grammars.

If our contribution would not go upstream to the Highlight JS library, how could we make it through to the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange site?

UPDATE: https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/193/391 writes that a request for another language was declined by Stack Exchange Staff as it would affect only one site.